# Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to go into a restaurant database and get 15 random restaurants printed to the console. Here is the code I am using:

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  const newMin = Math.ceil(min);
  const newMax = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (newMax - newMin) + newMin);
}

function dataHandler(dataArray) {
  console.log("fired dataHandler");
  console.table(dataArray);
  const range = [...Array(15).keys()];
  const listItems = range.map((item, index) => {
    const restNum = getRandomIntInclusive(0, dataArray - 1);
    return dataArray[restNum];
  });
  
  console.log(listItems);
  
  //range.forEach((item) => {
    //console.log("range item", item);
    //return[dataArray]
  //});
}

async function mainEvent() {
  console.log("script loaded");
  const form = document.querySelector(".main_form");
  const submit = document.querySelector(".submit_button");

  const results = await fetch(
    "https://data.princegeorgescountymd.gov/resource/umjn-t2iz.json"
  );
  const arrayFromJson = await results.json();
  console.log(arrayFromJson);

  if (arrayFromJson > 0) {
    submit.style.display = "block";
    form.addEventListener("submit", async (submitEvent) => {
      submitEvent.preventDefault();
      console.log("form submission");
      dataHandler(arrayFromJson);
    });
  }
}
```

The problems lies with restNum and returns an error that says:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataArray[restNum]')
```

I was wondering if anyone is able to help me debug this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is `dataHandler()` called? What does `dataArray` contain? First you use `dataArray - 1` as if `dataArray` is a number. Then you use `dataArray[restNum]` as if it is an array. It can't be both. (And judging by the error, it is neither.)

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. What would you suggest taking out? Just having restNum in the return statement?

Comment: `dataArray - 1` should most likely be `dataArray.length - 1`. But the main problem here is that `dataHandler()` is called with the wrong parameter value (which you're not showing here).

Comment: Okay. I made an edit to my post that shows my whole script. Maybe this will help

Comment: That code should not throw that error. `arrayFromJson > 0` should always be false (because `arrayFromJson` is an array so you're comparing an array to a number), so `dataHandler()` should never be called at all here.